# The HTTP request is unauthorized - client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'

Tags: wcf, authentication, ntlm

I know this question has already been asked on stack overflow before but the solutions don't seem to be working for me. I have a WCF service for which I have created a binding in code as I need to pass a username and password (couldn't find a way to do this in the configuration file).

Now from what I can see, NTLM authentication is just Windows authentication over HTTP? Enabling Windows authentication in IIS allows for this setting to be used doesn't it? Anyway I've also tried removing Negotiate (and vice versa) from the providers when right clicking on Windows Authentication in IIS leaving NTLM only but this doesn't work either.

The actual error that I get is:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm confused as to why this isn't working.